# Should the potential disadvantage of roaming settings cause me to duplicate them in local settings?

Tags: c#, windows-8, cloud, windows-store-apps, application-settings

There are two scenarios where storing my app's settings locally would seem preferable to roaming/in the cloud, namely:

```
1) When the user has (temporarily) lost internet connectivity
2) When/if retrieving roaming settings perceptibly impacts performance
```

So I'm thinking of storing settings both locally *and* via roaming, and only retrieving the roaming settings when I detect the device currently being used to run my app is not the 
one normally/initially used. Of course, I would still need *store* the roaming settings along with the local settings in any case.

IOW, I want to store locally for the scenarios mentioned above, but I also want to roam the settings in the event the user is using my app with a different device than originally.

Is this a sensible approach (duplicating settings both locally and in the cloud)? If so, is there a way to accomplish this semi-automatically rather than duplicating all the settings storing code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Roaming settings are available offline.  The only difference is that they will sync to other devices if you are online.  If you're offline it will just use the most recent version you have until you go online again.